# How to protect a resource(thread safe) in Boost serialization?

Tags: c++, multithreading, serialization, boost

I'm trying to use Boost Serialization library with several threads but I don't understand the process. The documentation says that the singleton class is the solution but it doesn't work.

I have the following code:

```
struct serialization
{
  template <typename TP>
  std::string serialize_to_string(const TP& data)
  {
    std::ostringstream output_archive_stream;
    boost::archive::polymorphic_text_oarchive archive( output_archive_stream );
    archive << data;
    return output_archive_stream.str();
  }

  template <typename TP>
  void deserialize_from_string(const std::string& data, TP& o)
  {
    std::istringstream input_stream(data);
    boost::archive::polymorphic_text_iarchive archive(input_stream);
    archive >> o;
  }
};

/* more code */

template <typename TP>
inline std::string serialize_to_string(const TP& source,
                                       boost::system::error_code& error)
{
  std::string result;

  try {
    auto render =
      boost::serialization::singleton<serialization>::get_const_instance();

      result = render.serialize_to_string( source );
  }
  catch ( std::exception& e ) {
    error = error::invalid_serialization;
    result = "";
  }

  return result;
}

template <typename TP>
inline void deserialize_from_string(const std::string& data,
                                    TP& o,
                                    boost::system::error_code & error)
{
  try {
    auto render =
      boost::serialization::singleton<serialization>::get_const_instance();

    render.deserialize_from_string( data, o );
  }
  catch ( std::exception& e ) {
    error = error::invalid_deserialization;
  }
}
```

Valgrind says:

```
==9026== Possible data race during write of size 8 at 0x5D6BDC0 by thread #2
==9026== Locks held: none
==9026==    at 0x5AD7CE0: std::locale::locale(std::locale::_Impl*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==9026==    by 0x5AD9E6E: std::locale::classic() (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==9026==    by 0x5596EEB: boost::archive::basic_text_iprimitive<std::istream>::basic_text_iprimitive(std::istream&, bool) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_serialization.so.1.55.0)
==9026==    by 0x55A02C9: boost::archive::text_iarchive_impl<boost::archive::naked_text_iarchive>::text_iarchive_impl(std::istream&, unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_serialization.so.1.55.0)
==9026==    by 0x574EF0: boost::archive::naked_text_iarchive::naked_text_iarchive(std::istream&, unsigned int) (text_iarchive.hpp:106)
==9026==    by 0x586125: boost::archive::detail::polymorphic_iarchive_route<boost::archive::naked_text_iarchive>::polymorphic_iarchive_route<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, unsigned int) (polymorphic_iarchive_route.hpp:200)
==9026==    by 0x574F86: boost::archive::polymorphic_text_iarchive::polymorphic_text_iarchive(std::istream&, unsigned int) (polymorphic_text_iarchive.hpp:36)

==9026== This conflicts with a previous write of size 8 by thread #1
==9026== Locks held: none
==9026==    at 0x5AD7CE0: std::locale::locale(std::locale::_Impl*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==9026==    by 0x5AD9E6E: std::locale::classic() (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==9026==    by 0x5597F0B: boost::archive::basic_text_oprimitive<std::ostream>::basic_text_oprimitive(std::ostream&, bool) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_serialization.so.1.55.0)
==9026==    by 0x55A1229: boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::text_oarchive_impl(std::ostream&, unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_serialization.so.1.55.0)
==9026==    by 0x5ABEAD: boost::archive::detail::polymorphic_oarchive_route<boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::text_oarchive> >::polymorphic_oarchive_route<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, unsigned int) (polymorphic_oarchive_route.hpp:190)
```

I'm learning C++ and I'm sure that I'm omitting something. Can anyone help me?

Cheers

Comment: Well, it's working with a static std::mutex.I have not found another solution.